# How to make Twitter-Bootstrap like buttons

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I basically want to create a button like the big "Download Bootstrap" button on this side: http://getbootstrap.com/

***Note: I want to create the button myself just with css & html and not with the twitter-bootstrap framework***

I was able to do it pretty well but then I noticed that there was a bug: http://jsfiddle.net/vk5DV/

If you zoom in while hovering over the button you will notice that in the corner of the button there is something wrong. I think the link itself gets styled with the white background but I have no idea why.

```
#googlink a {
    color: white;
    transition: all 0.2s linear 0s;
}
#googlink :hover {
    background-color: white !important;
    color: #99CC00;
}
```

why does the link get a white background too (and not only the button div)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use a div, just style the link (a).
Currently you are styling both the link and the div, which is not necessary - this creates conflicts and, semantically, is useless.

You would want to use a div only if you needed to nest multiple elements within it and then position the div to position all the elements at once (just an example).

Answer (score 2):

If a border-radius is added it seems ok

eg

```
#googlink :hover {
    background-color: white !important;
    border-radius: 6px;
    color: #99CC00;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/f3kzb/show/

Although if you simplify it a bit, i think it works fine with the code you already have. Also specified as a class to be used with any link.

http://jsfiddle.net/fe25t/

**html**

```
<div id="green">

<a href="http://google.com/" class="special-link">Google</a>

</div>
```

**css**

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#green {
    background-color: #99CC00;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}
.special-link {

    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: 40px;
    display: inline-flex;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    font-size: 65px;
    background-color: #99CC00;
    border: 2px solid white;
    color: white;
    transition: all 0.2s linear 0s;
}

.special-link:hover {
    background-color: white !important;
    color: #99CC00;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There you go.. check this out.. The hover border has to be round so that it does not overlap the normal border. This addition is under the hood of the main button border so it does not pop out at the corners.

```
#googlink :hover {
border-radius: 6px;
background-color: white !important;
color: #99CC00;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/47vDq/